# хочу сделать из обычной клавы миди

Tags: binding

смысл затеи перебиндить просто клавиши, как для миди
понятно что я не ожидаю что она начнет выдавать ноты, но мне хочется забиндить некоторым образом что бы программа например Muse Score 3 распозновала вход как с миди
возможно ли это, подскажите? еще очень интересный вопрос заключается в том как забиндить доп октывы кроме c major, тут все просто с ним C D E F G A B C , а дальше как
возможно ли каким либо образом заменить сделать что бы C уже читалась как новая октава
если не на тот форум, извиняюсь, но вроде это прямо относится к кодингу
за любую инфу буду благодарен
в общем нужна прога для биндинга клавиш
всем спасибо

Comment: Возможно, вам на [SoftwareRecommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Правда, он английский.

Comment: спасибо! ничего страшного гугл транслит мощь